# Get objects of related tables from a collection laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to pass the result of a searching action but I am facing a problem because it is returning an array and from that all the relationships of the table are not working

result view. For this I can only access the data on my table not the related data through relationships

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    @foreach ($result as $object)
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <h3>Details for the animal</h3>

                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <p><strong>Id: </strong>{{ $object->id }}</p>


                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    @endforeach
@endsection
```

Here is my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Animal;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
class SearchController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        Animal::all();
        return view('search.index');
    }
    public function postSearch(Request $request)
    {
        $serial_number = $request->input('search');
        $this->getResult($serial_number);
        return redirect()->route('result',$serial_number);
    }
    public function getResult($serial_number){
        $result = DB::table('slaughters')->where(function ($query) use ($serial_number) {
            $query->where('id','LIKE',"%$serial_number%");
        })->latest()->get();

        return view('search.result', ['result'=>$result]);


    }
}
```

And my routes

```
Route::get('/search','SearchController@index')->name('search');
Route::post('/get','SearchController@postSearch');
Route::get('/search/{result}','SearchController@getResult')->name('result');
```

I would like to access data from the table related to this one too. What am to do

Slaughter model

```
class Slaughter extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function animal(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Animal::class);
    }
```

Comment: Is there a reason that you are using the query builder instead of eloquent to fetch the search results? and please add the code from the relationship that your are talking about to the question.

Comment: How can I use eloquent there and I have updated the relatioshionships

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Controller:

```
use App\Slaughter;

public function getResult($serial_number) {
    $result = Slaughter::where('id', 'like', "%{$serial_number}%")
        ->with('user', 'animal')
        ->latest()
        ->get();

    return view('search.result', compact('result'));
}
```

In your view you can then access the relationships like so:

```
{{ $object->user }}

{{ $object->animal }}
```

Answer (score 2):

You must create model `Slaughter` and define relations.

And then you can get result:

```php
public function getResult($serial_number)
{
    $result = Slaughter::with(['name_of_relation_1', 'name_of_relation_2'])->latest()->get();

    return view('search.result', ['result'=>$result]);
}
```

Comment: So for the name_of_relation am I supposed to use the class or which name am I to use